# Particles-based models - Discrete or Continuous, why?

Tags: simulation

I have a theoritical question about particles-based simulator (Reeves,83). I don't know if my question is relevant and I apologize if not.

On each frame, the system generate particles and attribute to it properties and behaviour (speed, velocity, etc), some of them will die (disappear) after X seconds.

Is because the render is genereated on each frame, that we can classify this type of simulation as discrete ? if yes, I think that performant simulators that seems to produce "continuous" simulation, are produced things like video so 24-27 frames/s.
Is it a question of frame, or a number of frame ?

Thanks a lot